# App crash by showing Dialog in Timer (in runOnUiThread) after closing app.

Tags: java, android, timer, dialog

I'm making a little game and in it I have to check if a value is zero every second. When it is zero the game should stop and show a dialog instead.
As from now the game never ever shoud work until the app is reinstalled.

So, I have an timer with an timertask which executes a runOnUiThread.

Timer:

```
private void update(){
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask(){

        @Override
        public void run() {

            onChange();             
        }   

    },0,(1000* getResources().getInteger(R.integer.remove_speed_inSecond)));
}
```

runOnUiThread: (with try/catch to catch the exeption at this point but i want to fix and not just ignore it.)

```
private void onChange(){

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
                checkupifexpire();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }
      });
}
```

The Method where i show the dialog:

```
private void checkupifexpire() {
    if(eat == 0 || drink == 0 || wash == 0 || care == 0){
        dialog = new Dialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
        dialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog)
            {

                GameEngine.this.finish();
            }
        });
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_rip);
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

Always when I press the back button or just the home button then the App crashes.
Any Idea how to fix this?

Comment: Could you post the stacktrace on the fail please?

Comment: A little more information would be helpful - what's the exception thrown when it crashes?

Comment: The exception in the logcat is very big... here the most of it:
http://img842.imageshack.us/img842/5706/logcat.png

Comment: Debugg: http://img823.imageshack.us/img823/204/debuggt.png

Comment: post your dialog layout code. and your New Dialog this refer to activity, right?

Comment: you can just stop the timer and restart it when your activity is called bact to screen. is this good solution for you?

Comment: @WELLCZECH : year i forgot to stop the timer.

Comment: @besnep OK. do you need some help with "when to stop that timer" or now you have it done?

Comment: @WELLCZECH : Thats a good question.. :/ if i stop the timer in the onCancel i'm stoping the timer in the timer oO don't know if that's a problem.
I also put the timer.stop in the onPause, onBackPressed and the onStop. 
The exeption is away but longcat it still throwing the same...

Comment: @besnep OK. first please read this few lines about android activity livecycle ( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle ) to handle right time when you need to stop your timer. It's werry useful. And then can u post `whole` log output. Then i hope i understand this problem :D

Comment: http://shortText.com/CyZGT1

Comment: When i change the position....portrai..landscape everytime it slows a bit down... longcat is running.. und then it crashes.
Debugg: http://img812.imageshack.us/img812/204/debuggt.png

Comment: @besnep OK. it seems that you are calling `checkupifexpire` method before your activity fully starts. I think in `access method` on line 296. And this throws this exceptions. It's because you dont have your own app window or how to say it. Simply you want to display dialog before is your app on screen. Do you understand me? Try to check this.

Comment: @WELLCZECH : Oh you coud be right... thats a realy good point.
But in my situation, when the dialog is called..the main app don't realy have to exist. It just coud be canceld with finish().
But thats imposible because then the dialog is fineshed too.. :/
And i also can't start a new activity from the timer i think.

Comment: @besnep In logcat output you can see on line 13 from top that system call onChange method after you init action bar. And there you call something on UI thread (i think it's some runnable instance) and that call access method and this method call check...method where is Dialog.show(). this all heapends immediately after onCreate is called so its after applicatin is created or rotated but not "showed" yet.

Comment: Thx to Neil Townsend and WELLCZECH! :) 
But i just thought to complicated...because when i wanted this dialog to show, the main app isn't used anymore so why shoud i start a dialog anyway^^ 
My solution now is that i just startet a new activity and canceld the main acitivity.

Comment: @WELLCZECH : Realy thank you for your time and effort! :) 
You where realy helpfull! And make me understand the Lifecycle of my App alittle bit better. 
So thank you very much :)

Comment: @besnep If only a little bit then i am disappointed. No i am kidding. If you will need another help in future you know where to find us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Neil Townsend and WELLCZECH. :)
My problem was the Lifecycles.

Mostly i had the App running in the onCreat() and had no onStart() method. 
Just didn't know that thies methods were as much important as they are.

Also i didn't need a dialog shown. Instead i just have to start a new activity and cancel the old one.

Comment: HI besnep - it's generally considered good protocol on StackOverflow to give the tick to the people you are thanking rather than putting your thanks in your own answer :-)

Comment: Oh sorry, i thought to make the tick there where the solution for my problem is^^ So your answer is not the solution, it just helped to get the solution. And in the end WELLCZECH found out that i never wrote a onStart() method, means that i have to give him the Tick.
But he never wrote a answer. 
I woud realy like to give your answer a "usefull" voteup (i tryed and hope i can make it in the future) but a have less then 15 reputation points :(

Comment: Fair enough, that makes sense!

Answer (score 3):

So, the logcat tells us that is crashes on line 306 of GameEngine.java, in the method checkupifexpire, which looks like it is the `dialog.show()` line.

I'm not 100% sure, but from what you've said, it would seem to me that when back or home is pressed, the app will lose its UI thread. This means that `checkuponexpire` cannot do what it does.

To solve your crash problem, there are three obvious options:

1. You could use `onPause` in your main activity to catch when the app loses the screen. At this point you need to either stop the timer, or switch it to using Toast to communicate information.
2. Only use Toast in `checkuponexpire`
3. Decide that when the back or home is pressed the game is over anyway and cancel the Timer.

To Actually get the dialog, it may also be helpful to change the context you use to create the dialog with. Although it should be used sparingly, it may be that `getApplicationContext()` is what you need here (possibly `this.getApplicationContext()`).

Comment: Thx. 1. worked to avoid the exeption.
But longcat it still throwing the same.... oO

Comment: Which did you do? change to Toast or stop the Timer?

Comment: I hadn't stoped the timer... so year i stoped the timer.

Comment: Year, seems like.. the App stops crashing but the longcat still throws errors.

Comment: Answer updated - if it solved the thing a tick would be appreciated - afraid I'mm logging off now, hope it helped.

Comment: Thx to Neil Townsend and WELLCZECH! :) 
But i just thought to complicated...because when i wanted this dialog to show, the main app isn't used anymore so why shoud i start a dialog anyway^^ 
My solution now is that i just startet a new activity and canceld the main acitivity.